# move $messages div to inside the form tag

Tags: webforms

I would like to move the $messages div for any webform type away from a div but instead add it inside the  tag. I've started with THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) in my template.php but I am stuck because the $variables doesnt set which element (or id/classes) the $messages should be placed in. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy your [webform-form.tpl.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21templates%21webform-form.tpl.php/7) from the contrib webform module folder (under templates) to your themes templates folder and make the modifications there.

Default code:

```
if (isset($form['preview_message'])) {
  print '<div class="messages warning">';
  print drupal_render($form['preview_message']);
  print '</div>';
}
```

Comment: The $messages variable cannot be access in that template... So I cant use this solution..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or elaborate a little more on what messages, I am kind of having a brain fart as to which you mean.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the regular page.tpl.php status messages not webform specific? If so try themeing the [status messages](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7)